# How to implement different "Branches" in react native stack navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I used to use react-native-router-flux a while ago, it uses nested Scenes to implement different "branches" so, you can keep track of navigation history and life cycle of each branch independently, something like:

```
<Router sceneStyle={{ paddingTop: 65 }}>
      <Scene key="auth">
        <Scene key="login" component={LoginForm} title="Please Login" />
      </Scene>

      <Scene key="main">
        <Scene
          title="Employees"
          initial
        />
        <Scene key="employeeCreate" component={EmployeeCreate} title="Create Employee" />
        <Scene key="employeeEdit" component={EmployeeEdit} title="Edit Employee" />
      </Scene>
 </Router>
```

When migrating to react-navigation , how to implement this "nesting" approach?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how "Nesting" or "Branching" works in `react-native-router-flux` but looking at your code above, I believe the closest thing to it is a `SwitchNavigator` in React Navigation. You can use it for authentication flows. You'll make a separate `StackNavigator` for pre-Log in state of the app, and one for post-Log in state. Something like this:

```
import { createSwitchNavigator, createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

const main = createStackNavigator({
    employees: Employees,
    employeeCreate: EmployeeCreate,
    employeeEdit: EmployeeEdit
});
const auth = createStackNavigator({ login: LoginForm });

export default createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    App: main,
    Auth: auth,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Auth',
    navigationOptions: { header: null }
  }
);
```

However, remember that when you move from one stack to the other, the previous stack will be reset (all information in that previous stack will be lost, and you can't go from one stack to the other by simply pressing `Back` button).

Take a look at the official documentation [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/auth-flow.html) for more detailed example. There is a Medium post [here](https://medium.com/the-react-native-log/building-an-authentication-flow-with-react-navigation-fb5de2203b5c) (though a bit out-dated) that might help you out as well.

Comment: I tried that approach already, it gives me two headers for each screen ! my main goal is to have separate domains for each stack, so, for example when i navigate from login screen to main home screen, there is no back button by default

Comment: Are you using a custom header, or do you want a header to be generated by `react-navigation`? If you have a custom one then use `navigationOptions: { header: null }` to remove the header generated by `react-navigation`.